# Magnify entire dock instead of where the cursor is?

Tags: macos, dock

Is it possible to magnify the entire dock when putting the cursor over it, instead of just magnifying where the cursor is? When putting the cursor over the dock, the whole dock would become the magnified size. If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

You could get most of the functionality by:

1. Turn Hiding on - you now need to mouse over to grow it.
2. Turn Magnification off - since all the dock needs to be the same size
3. Making the dock super large when it's visible - so when you mouse to it, it's zoomed to your preference.

No, in that you can't have a small bit of the dock on screen and then have that visible dock get larger when your cursor is on it.